# I am getting this error styling my portfolio in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, portfolio, visual-web-developer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeSwitcher extends InheritedWidget {
  final _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState data; // We'll use ThemeSwitcher to get access to the current state of ThemeSwitcherWidget

  const ThemeSwitcher({
    Key key,
    @required this.data,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState of(BuildContext context) { //This method returns the current state of the ThemeSwitcherWidget. This will be used down the tree
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(ThemeSwitcher)
    as ThemeSwitcher)
        .data;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ThemeSwitcher old) {
    return this != old;
  }
}

class ThemeSwitcherWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool initialDarkModeOn; // this is the initial state of the variable
  final Widget child; // child to which this boolean variable should be propagated upon change. This will be our app in this case

  ThemeSwitcherWidget({Key key, this.initialDarkModeOn, this.child})
      : assert(initialDarkModeOn != null),
        assert(child != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState createState() => _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState();
}


class _ThemeSwitcherWidgetState extends State<ThemeSwitcherWidget> {
  bool isDarkModeOn;

  void switchDarkMode() {  //method used to toggle dark mode during the runtime of the app
    setState(() {
      isDarkModeOn = !isDarkModeOn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isDarkModeOn = isDarkModeOn ?? widget.initialDarkModeOn; // this is the build method which would build the widget tree with the above info
    return ThemeSwitcher(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
>   Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.

This is the Error I am continuously facing the issue after trying many methods.

I would like to know how would this problem can be solved as I am not getting any good solution from searches.

---

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the following statement in **_ThemeSwitcherWidgetState of(BuildContext context)** method of your code:

```
return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<ThemeSwitcher>()).data;
```